# activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation() is always 0

Tags: android

I am working on a Camera application 
but in the `setCameraOrientation` when i am trying to get the display rotation i am always getting 0 in `rotation`

```
/**If you want to make the camera image show in the same orientation as the display, you can use the following code.
*/
  public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
          int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
      android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
              new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
      android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
      int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
      int degrees = 0;
      switch (rotation) {
          case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
          case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
          case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
          case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
      }

      int result;
      if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
          result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
          result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
      } else {  // back-facing
          result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
      }
      camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
  }
```

called this method in `onSurfaceChanged`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0)
if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_90)
if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_180)
if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270)
```

Comment: @Prasanath S ,i am still getting rotation 0

Comment: @DeepanshuNamdeo try .  WindowManager windowManager =  (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    int rotation = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

Comment: @Prasanath nothing is happening, still 0

Answer (score 0):

This happens in my phone (Samsung J3 Prime) if auto-rotate is turned off.